# Loading DEM .asc file in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem

Loading a DEM dataset with .asc extension in Arcmap 10.7 (here the dataset http://www.sardegnageoportale.it/webgis2/sardegnamappe/?map=download_raster - select "DTM passo 10"; here the file http://webgis.regione.sardegna.it/scaricocartografiaETL/modelliDigitali/DTM10m/478.zip)
one of the elements of the mosaic is not displayed correctly. In fact, it appears in a single shade of gray and shows a range of elevation values that do not correspond to the real values.
[image]
The same item displayed in qgis 3.10 does not show the same problems and displays correctly.
I tried to open the file with a text editor but without being able to identify the problem by comparing it with the other files of the dataset that are displayed correctly.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you use the info tool and click on a pixel does it give expected values? If so is probably a rendering issue which will go away when you mosaic the ASC files into a single raster.

Comment: Any changes with various zoom levels?

Comment: @Hornbydd, Thank You very much: using the "Mosaic to new raster" tool to merge the individual files into one, as you suggested, solved the problem.